# Show that $A^{*}A$ is non singular iff $A$ has full rank.

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ $\in \mathbb{C^{mxn}}, m \geq n$.

Show that $A^*A$ is non-singular iff $A$ has full rank.

I can think of a way to do this if $A$ is a square matrix of order $nxn$.

I would suppose that $A$ is not full rank, which would imply det $A$ = 0, which in turn would imply det $A^*A$ is also $0$.
Similar method would be used for the converse.

How to go about an $m$x$n$ matrix?

Edit: I have tried this.

Let $A$ be full rank $\implies A$ has $n$ singular values.

The singular value decomposition gives us:
$A=U.\sum.V^*
\implies A^*A=V.\sum^2.V^*
\implies |A^*A| = \pm \prod_{i=1}^{n} \sigma_i^{2} \neq 0 \implies A^*A$ is non-singular.

[ I have used the property of unitary matrices, $UU^*=I$ and the fact that the determinant of a unitary matrix has absolute value 1, above.]

Conversely, let $A^*A$ be non-singular.

Thus, $|A^*A| \neq 0 \implies \pm \prod_{i=1}^{n} \sigma_i^{2} \neq 0$ which is possible only if $\sum$ is a diagonal matrix of order $n$, i.e. $A$ is full rank.

Comment: I was recently reading a paper that needed something similar, and their proof said "one can use the singular value decomposition", so that would work. But I wouldn't be surprised if there wasn't a much simpler proof also.

Comment: I was actually using that. But I’m not sure if it works. I’ll type it out in the edit.

Comment: There's nothing like trying to explain your proof to someone else for checking to see if it works!

Comment: Note that any matrix has SVD and it is unique. If matrix doesn't have full rank, then remaining values in diagonal will be zero. Therefore, your proof for right to left is actually works for left to right as well.

Comment: @Snowball got it. Okay.

Comment: Your proof is in principle fine, but the assumption that $A$ being full rank implies it has $n$ non-zero singular values makes it almost circular. I would've assumed that this assumption is part of what you're trying to prove.

Comment: @EuYu Can you help out with that? How do I prove that a full rank matrix $A$ has $n$ singular values? Or is there any material somewhere that could help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler approach:
$$|Ax|^2=x^* A^* A x = 0 \Leftrightarrow |Ax|=0 \Leftrightarrow x\in {\rm ker A}$$
You deduce from this  that ${\rm ker} A^* A = {\rm ker }A$.

As $m\geq n$, $A^*A$ is non-singular (so is an invertible matrix) iff $A$ has full rank.